# Facing DateFormat issue in Android, CDT converting into IST

Tags: java, android

The time I am getting from Android phone is

"Mon May  9 09:34:13 CDT 2016\r\r\n" but after parsing the same date using date format SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",Locale.US);

After parsing it gives me a date into the

"Mon May 09 20:04:56 IST 2016".

It clearly shows that the hours is increase by 11 hours.

How to address this issue, Could anybody help me?

Comment: Have you considered using Joda time?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Actually, the time-of-day is different by 10.5 hours, not 11. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51201955/642706) for explanation.

Comment: Was the `:56` in your IST example a typo? Should that have been `:13` like the CDT value above it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

Your India time is correctly adjusted 10.5 hours ahead of Chicago time. Feature, not a bug. (I am assuming your `:56` seconds was a typo in your Question.)

If you want no such adjustment, but instead want the same date and same time-of-day assigned to a different time zone, then do this:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse(
    "Mon May 9 09:34:13 CDT 2016" ,  // If at all possible, avoid using such an awful format for exchanging date-time strings. Always use standard ISO 8601 formats instead.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z uuuu" )
)                                    // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.withZoneSameLocal( 
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) 
)                                    // Returns a fresh `ZonedDateTime` object, with values based on the original but for the change in assigned zone.
.toString()                          // Generates a String is standard ISO 8601 format, extending the standard by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.
```

> 2016-05-09T09:34:13+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

We get the same date and same time-of-day, but a different offset-from-UTC means this is a different moment, a different point on the timeline.

## Correct values

[Note: I am assuming the `:56` in your `Mon May 09 20:04:56 IST 2016` was a typo, and should have been `:13`. ]

The strings `Mon May 9 09:34:13 CDT 2016` and `Mon May 09 20:04:13 IST 2016` represent the same moment. This is a feature, not a bug. If by `CDT` you mean a time zone such as `America/Chicago`, that value on that date represents a moment five hours *behind* UTC, `-05:00`. If by `IST`, you mean a time zone such as `Asia/Kolkata`, India on that date is five and a half hours *ahead* of UTC, `+05:30`. Add those offsets together, and we get a difference of ten and a half hours. This fits: `09:34:13` plus 10.5 hours is `20:04:13`.

In other words, if someone in Chicago is talking to someone in Kolkata on the telephone, if they both look up at the time on the clock on their own wall, one will see 09:34:13 while the other sees 20:04:13.

Perhaps you wanted to purposely *not* adjust for time zone, but re-create the same date with the same time-of-day but in a different time zone. This would *not* be the same moment, this would a different point on the timeline. See below for such code.

## java.time

You are using troublesome old classes that were supplanted long ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

When possible, avoid manipulating strings as a way of handling date-time. Instead, use smart objects, not dumb strings.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline, but different wall-clock time.
```

If you must exchange date-time values as text, use standard ISO 8601 formats rather than formats such as seen in your Question.

Also, never use the 3-4 letter pseudo-time-zones such as `CDT` or `IST`. These are not true time zones, are not standardized, and many are not unique(!). Use full time zone names is the [IANA-specified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) `Continent/Region` format.

But to your Question directly, parsing the string `Mon May 9 09:34:13 CDT 2016`. Define a formatting pattern to match.

```
String input = "Mon May 9 09:34:13 CDT 2016";

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z uuuu" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2016-05-09T09:34:13-05:00[America/Chicago]

### `ZonedDateTime::withZoneSameInstant`

Adjust into India time.

```
ZoneId zKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( zKolkata );
```

> zdtKolkata.toString(): 2016-05-09T20:04:13+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

Same behavior as you saw with the legacy classes. Adding 10.5 hours to 09:34:13 gets us 20:04:13. Same moment, same point on the timeline, but different wall-clock time.

### `ZonedDateTime::withZoneSameLocal`

But what if you want the same date and same time-of-day, but switch out the time zone? This would result in a different moment, different points on the timeline (assuming the two zones don’t share the same offset). The `ZonedDateTime` does support this manipulation via the [`ZonedDateTime::withZoneSameLocal​(ZoneId zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameLocal(java.time.ZoneId)) method.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtSameLocalKolkata = zdt.withZoneSameLocal( zKolkata );
```

> zdtSameLocalKolkata.toString(): 2016-05-09T09:34:13+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

Now we see the time-of-day unchanged, still 09:34:13. But the offset-from-UTC is different than Chicago, so we know this does *not* represent the same moment.

You can verify the fact they are different moments by adjusting both into UTC. The easy way to make that adjustment is to extract `Instant` object. An `Instant` is always in UTC by definition.

```
Instant instantOfZdtChicago = zdt.toInstant() ;
Instant instantOfZdtSameLocalKolkata = zdtSameLocalKolkata.toInstant():
```

> instantOfZdtChicago.toString(): 2016-05-09T14:34:13Z
>
> instantOfZdtSameLocalKolkata.toString(): 2016-05-09T04:04:13Z

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget **Date** class is a class with no format at all....

if you want to print a date you need to use the format method of the intenace you created...

## example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String myDate = "Mon May 9 09:34:13 CDT 2016";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
    Date d = dateFormat.parse(myDate);
    System.out.println(d);  // this is not formatted printing Mon May 09 16:34:13 CEST 2016
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(d)); // this is printed using the same format you use above
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, the issue is after parsing the date the timezone is getting change, How I can make sure the time zone should not change after parsing the date.

Comment: String lastDate = "03:59:58 10/05/2016";\n
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy");\n
System.out.println("::NEW::"+dateFormat.parse(lastDate));\n
        System.out.println("::OLD::"+dateFormat.format(dateFormat.parse(lastDate)));\n

Comment: The Output I am getting is :\n

::NEW::Sun Jan 10 03:05:58 IST 2016
::OLD::03:05:58 10/05/2016